# Random numbers in C++ and Mathematica gives wrong results?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, c++

I have the following strange phenomenon which puzzles me!:

I have a **piecewise constant probability density** given as

```
using RandomGenType = std::mt19937_64;
RandomGenType gen(51651651651);

using PREC = long double;
std::array<PREC,5> intervals {0.59, 0.7, 0.85, 1, 1.18};
std::array<PREC,4> weights {1.36814, 1.99139, 0.29116, 0.039562};

 // integral over the pdf to normalize:
PREC normalization =0;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<4;i++){
    normalization += weights[i]*(intervals[i+1]-intervals[i]);
}
std::cout << std::setprecision(30) << "Normalization: " << normalization << std::endl;
// normalize all weights (such that the integral gives 1)!
for(auto & w : weights){
    w /= normalization;
}

std::piecewise_constant_distribution<PREC>
distribution (intervals.begin(),intervals.end(),weights.begin());
```

When I draw `n` random numbers (radius of sphere in millimeters) from this distribution and compute the mass of the sphere and sum them up like:

```
unsigned int n = 1000000;
double density = 2400;
double mass = 0;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    auto d = 2* distribution(gen) * 1e-3;
    mass += d*d*d/3.0*M_PI_2*density;
}
```

I get **mass = 4.3283 kg**  (see [LIVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c9d062f5153ce9e) and the [c++ post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862895/floating-point-math-rounding-weird-in-c-compared-to-mathematica))

Doing the EXACT identical thing in Mathematica like:

[image: Graphic]

Gives the assumably correct value of **4.5287 kg**.

Which is not the same, also with different seeds , C++ and Mathematica never match! ? Is that numeric inaccuracy, which I doubt it is...?
**Question : What the hack is wrong with the sampling in C++?**

**Simple Mathematica Code:**

```
pdf[r_] = 2*Piecewise[{{0, r < 0.59}, {1.36814, 0.59 <= r <= 0.7}, 
           {1.99139, Inequality[0.7, Less, r, LessEqual, 0.85]}, 
           {0.29116, Inequality[0.85, Less, r, LessEqual, 1]}, 
           {0.039562, Inequality[1, Less, r, LessEqual, 1.18]}, 
           {0, r > 1.18}}];

pdfr[r_] = pdf[r] / Integrate[pdf[r], {r, 0, 3}];(*normalize*)

Plot[pdf[r], {r, 0.4, 1.3}, Filling -> Axis]

PDFr = ProbabilityDistribution[pdfr[r], {r, 0, 1.18}]; 
(*if you put 1.18=2 then we dont get 4.52??*)

SeedRandom[100, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]
dataR = RandomVariate[PDFr, 1000000, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
Fold[#1 + (2*#2*10^-3)^3  Pi/6 2400 &, 0, dataR] 

(*Analytical Solution*)

PDFr = ProbabilityDistribution[pdfr[r], {r, 0, 3}];
1000000 Integrate[ 2400 (2 InverseCDF[PDFr, p] 10^-3)^3 Pi/6, {p, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: the *pdf* you supply to `ProbabilityDistribution` must be a proper probability density function in the sense that it integrates to unity over the interval. ( yours integrates to ~1/2 )

Comment: ups jeah, sorry, should be 2 times this, (edit)

Comment: Do You have to update that 2 factor in your C-Code?.

Also, i don't get why "2* distribution(gen)" when drawing random numbers.

Comment: With 2* ()  -> it is a valid PDF which integrates to almost 1 -> in the c++ code it is not needed as these are weights (where the 2* cancels out, you can add it is does not change anything)

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I see that with n=2000000 your C-code gives 8.65219 and Mathematica 9.0509. (The difference increases with n). I suppose this should not be correct, isn't it?

Comment: Jeah the difference increases with n, somthing is fishy here, it seems an accuracy problem, hm.... very strange

Comment: There is cancelation, with huge numbers!! adding small mass to the accumlation!! I thinks its this, I think one should do a Reduction operation to sum all masses

Comment: Nope also a reduction , does not help-> see the updated code !!

Comment: Isn't this more of a C++ question than a *Mathematica* one?

Comment: The c++ question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862895/floating-point-math-rounding-weird-in-c-compared-to-mathematica?noredirect=1#comment45998454_28862895

Comment: whats wrong  with ``PDFr = ProbabilityDistribution[pdfr[r], {r, 0, 3}]; `` in the above code, this will give a completely other value (4.46 something) but it should be the same since the pdf is zero after 1.18 ???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it describes a problem exhibited by code in C++ rather than Mathematica.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a bit of an extended comment,

Note there is no need for a delayed defintion of your  pdf:

```
 pdf[r_] = 
   Simplify[2 (Piecewise[{{0, r <= 0.59}, {1.36814, 
     Inequality[0.59, Less, r, LessEqual, 0.7]}, {0, r > 0.7}}, 
   Indeterminate] + 
  Piecewise[{{0, r <= 0.7}, {1.99139, 
     Inequality[0.7, Less, r, LessEqual, 0.85]}, {0, r > 0.85}}, 
   Indeterminate] + 
  Piecewise[{{0., r <= 0.85}, {0.29116, 
     Inequality[0.85, Less, r, LessEqual, 1]}, {0., r > 1}}, 
   Indeterminate] + 
  Piecewise[{{0, r <= 1}, {0.039562, 
     Inequality[1, Less, r, LessEqual, 1.18]}, {0, r > 1.18}}, 
   Indeterminate])];
```

This integrates to nearly 1, but lets normalize it so its exact: (the factor is ~0.999998 )

```
 pdf[r_] =  pdf[r]/Integrate[ pdf[r], {r, .59, 1.18}] // Simplify
```

[image]

Now you can get your result analytically: (this fails if you don't do the normalization)

```
 PDFr = ProbabilityDistribution[pdf[r], {r, 0.59, 1.18}];
 1000000 Integrate[ 2400 ( 2 InverseCDF[PDFr, p] 10^-3)^3 Pi/6  , {p, 0, 1}]
```

> 4.52594

This is true because:
 [image: Math]

This seems fairly convincing that your mathematica monte carlo is correct and the trouble lies in the c version.

Comment: Jeap, I tested that too! Thanks for the comment! it seems that the c++ is buggy!

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, I did not test that, can you quickly give me a hint, why you integrate the inverse cdf? The term ``Integrate[ 2400 ( 2 InverseCDF[PDFr, p] 10^-3)^3 Pi/6  , {p, 0, 1}]``is the expected mass of one sphere I assume, but why :-)?